# App cannot be download in google play store

Tags: android, google-play-services

i use a device - Samsung Galaxy J1. But, Play store show the app cannot download.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

I check that the device support OpenGL ES 3, camera with auto focus. Anyone know if you specify android:glEsVersion="0x00020000", then the device with OpenGL Es 3 will not be downloaded? Is this the reason?

Update:

SDK setting

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

Samsung Galaxy J1 support Android 4.4 and 5.1. Suppose the device is supported

Comment: Check the Play store through a browser to see if it's there in the first place

Comment: 0x00020000 is for OpenGL ES 2.0 , so this cannot be the reason. Check if the min sdk is compatible with your device.

Comment: min sdk is 15. target sdk is 23. Suppose the device support

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8fIuVk2SpQ

Found someone fix this issue by clear google play store cache. So sad =[

Comment: @KingWu, does clearing cache work for you?